# Dropdown Menu - Open Link in Parent Window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code below in a pop up window, I would like to open it in the parent window if possible.

**Javascript:**

```
var getURL = function () {
    var option1 = document.getElementById('dropDown1').value;
    var option2 = document.getElementById('dropDown2').value;
    var URL = 'http://www.domain.com/' + option1 + '/' + option2;
    location.href = (URL);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<select id="dropDown1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select id="dropDown2">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<button onclick="getURL()">Run</button>
```

The code works fine but it only opens in the current window.

Any help would be great :) thanks

Comment: Did you try window.opener.location ?

Comment: Which one is your `Parent window`? Do you want popup in different window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below js to open your page in new window instead of `location.href=(URL)`.

```
window.open(URL,"_blank");
```

Comment: This worked great, i changed "_blank" to "_parent" and it worked fine, thanks Ranjana